# Why is Tensorflow.js fftSize different by a factor of two to the Web Audio API fftSize?

Tags: fft, tensorflow.js

[`tf.data.microphone`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#data.microphone) has an `fftSize` parameter, described as "the number of samples used to compute each nonoverlapping “frame” of audio" in the *Deep Learning with JavaScript* book.

However, when a browser `AnalyserNode` is configured, this number is doubled:

```
   this.analyser.fftSize = this.fftSize * 2;
```

(see [`microphone_iterator.ts`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-data/src/iterators/microphone_iterator.ts#L128)).

The [`AnalyserNode.fftSize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/fftSize) is also described as, "the window size in samples that is used when performing a FFT".

Why is this quantity doubled?

I suspect part of the reason is that there is a related quantity to the widow size, namely the number of frequency bins, which is set to [half the fftSize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/frequencyBinCount). Indeed, in the source of `MicrophoneIterator`, `fftSize` looks to be used as the number of frequency bins:

```
    this.freqData = new Float32Array(this.fftSize);
    ...
    this.analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(this.freqData)
```

But elsewhere it is used as if it were indeed the window size - here's the polling interval for frames:

```
    this.fftSize / this.sampleRateHz * 1e3
```

Hoping someone can clarify the precise interpretation of this parameter for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the browser Analyser is configured" ?

Comment: @edkeveked - when the `Analyser.fftSize` is set: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-data/src/iterators/microphone_iterator.ts#L128